# Security of WCF endpoints

Tags: wcf, security

For the sake of argument, lets say that I've got a basicHttp WCF service. Besides implementing authentication (login/logout methods), what is stopping someone from just cracking open Visual Studio, adding a web reference to my website's service, and then playing playing around with my service? I'm not familiar with a method of stopping someone from doing this. The idea of someone downloading all of my Data/Operation contracts and then start playing around is keeping me up at night, and I like my sleep!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Discoverability *is **the** driving factor* behind Web Services and especially SOAs.  The ability of anyone at all who can reach the service to pull up the WSDL, generate a proxy in Visual Studio (or some other tool), and start using the service is one of the main reasons to create a web service!

I suppose you could generate all the client proxies and then disable the mex endpoint, but that pretty much cripples WCF, and even then it's only security through obscurity.

If you don't want any miscreant to start hitting your web service then either don't use the `basicHttpBinding` (which is designed for the express purpose of immediate and anonymous consumption) or host the service on a private network which only trusted clients can reach.

Comment: +1 good points. Yes, by turning off all metadata-related functions (no "serviceMetadata" behavior, no MEX endpoint) you can pretty much "hide" your service - only those who specifically know where it lives and how to access it will be able to do so. Assume however that your worst enemies *do* know.....

Comment: Thanks for the post. I thought about removing the mex endpoint, but I figured there would have to be more to it than that.

Answer (score 1):

Some form of authentication or encryption is the only thing that can prevent this. You have to distinguish between those you want give access to, and those you don't. Give the ones you want to have access the certificate necessary to do encryption, or the username and password.

Don't give anything to the others.